# Querying individual classes within two versions of an ontology in OwlReady2

Tags: ontology, owlready

I'm trying to query a single concept in the Vaccine Ontology (https://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/VO) to check differences between two versions.

According to Owlready2 documentation you can query a class after importing the ontology as:

```
vo_1 = owlready2.get_ontology('./sources/VO_merged_23_11_23.owl').load()
vo_2 = owlready2.get_ontology('./sources/VO_merged_24_01_03.owl').load()
vac = IRIS['http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/VO_0000001']
```

I can't seem to find a way to call the concept VO_0000001 within each different version of VO.

I tried vo_1.vac / vo_1.VO_0000001 and vo_1.obo.VO_0000001 but they all yielded NoneType objects.